# Median of an Array

Tags: arrays, sorting, delphi, median

Hey guys i am developing with Delphi 10 Seattle. And i actually need help at getting a Median of an Array eg :

```
 allitems: array[1..500] of Double;
```

I gave the value of each arrayitem in the array in a procedure. So i got an array of 500 doubles with values in it and want to get the Median out of this 500 values. First of all i guess i have to sort the array from low to high values and after it getting the median. So How can i sort the array first and get the median after sorting ?

Comment: Here's a link to a sort method of the TArray class.  It might help get you started on the sort:  http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Generics_Collections_TArray_Sort@array_of_T.html

Comment: You might find this Wikipedia page useful, too:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Comment: This is nothing at all to do with the median value. Your question is simply, "How can I sort an array?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Median of an even number of elements is defined as the mean of the center elements:

```
var
  allitems : TArray<double>;

  TArray.Sort<double>(allitems);
  median := (allitems[249] + allitems[250]) / 2; // TArray<double> starts with index 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I get how you got the median but how do you sort the array or why are you defining array new ? i just defined my array like in my question. And TArray.Sort is not working ( undeclared identifier TArray)

Comment: Have you included "System.Generics.Collections" as indicated by the documentation link in the comments to your question?

Comment: You are presumably using some ancient version of Delphi @Liam?

Comment: @Gloegg In English that should be **number** of elements. Sorry, my pet hate.

Comment: ah ok thanks i got it! i just had to include system.generics.collection. tanks @DNR

Answer (score 1):

The working algorithm you can find on [rosettacode.org](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Averages/Median#Delphi):

```
program AveragesMedian;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses Generics.Collections, Types;

function Median(aArray: TDoubleDynArray): Double;
var
  lMiddleIndex: Integer;
begin
  TArray.Sort<Double>(aArray);

  lMiddleIndex := Length(aArray) div 2;
  if Odd(Length(aArray)) then
    Result := aArray[lMiddleIndex]
  else
    Result := (aArray[lMiddleIndex - 1] + aArray[lMiddleIndex]) / 2;
end;

begin
  Writeln(Median(TDoubleDynArray.Create(4.1, 5.6, 7.2, 1.7, 9.3, 4.4, 3.2)));
  Writeln(Median(TDoubleDynArray.Create(4.1, 7.2, 1.7, 9.3, 4.4, 3.2)));
end.
```