# Algorithm to find "the middle" of several inputs under a given deviation/proportion

Tags: algorithm, delphi

I need to design an algorithm to find out the middle of several input given a variation percentage.
What will happen in reality.
I have a scale and more pieces of the same product. Like 20 bottle of yogurt of 200g each piece. But in reality each bottle can differ in weight by a small amount.
Why? Because in reality a producer can have small deviation.
One bottle will be putted on the scale and a weight will be received. The received weight is 208 g. The next one will be putted and received weight is 203 g. And so on. However a mistake is made and someone put a different bottle like yogurt of 502g.
What I need to design is an algorithm to exclude the mistakes and "at the end of the day" to came up with a "proper" weight for the product.
Lets say the accepted variation is 10%. That means a bottle with "the middle" of "200g" can have correct values of 180 - 220 g.
How can I find the middle?
Keep in mind that I don't have any information about what will be weighing next. What I receive is an ID of the product and a weight. Like 14 and 208g. 45 and 504. 14 and 300. 14 and 210.
Many tks in advance

Comment: The "middle" as you name it and as I understand is usually named the "mean". It is the sum of values dived by the number of values. Here you have several products identified by an ID, so you must keep a sum and a count for each ID. In delphi programming, you have an array (or a list or a dictionary) of records. Each record is ID, Sum and Count (For a dictionary, ID is the key and record of sum and count is the item). When you need the mean for an ID, you simply search the ID in the array and compute sum/count.

Comment: that is not correct. I need to exclude the "wrong" values. like 500g from an array of 200.

Comment: Can you trust that the product ID is correct? Is there a correlation between product ID and weight (like e.g. ID=14 has nominal w=200g)? Do all products have non-overlapping weight tolerances? The task is impossible if any of those question have a negative answer. For tasks like this you must demand proper definitions. And if you want help here you must repeat those definitions.

Comment: Once you get the mean or median, you can elimitate all values out of the acceptable range around and recompute the mean or median. This will be OK if the number of out of range is low compared to accepted value range. If you know the expected value range, you can eliminate the out of range as soon as you see it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have outliers in your data, then you should not use the mean value. A robust estimate of the 'middle' in the presence of outliers is the median value, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median. An example how to compute the median can be found at [Median of an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727848/median-of-an-array).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the [Median value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) is what you expect to compute.

There is a rough algorithm to implement it: sort all values, then pick the one in the middle.

Here is something more optimized, which won't sort all values, but only the needed values, so is faster:

```
function MedianQuickSelectInteger(Values: PIntegerArray; n: integer): integer;
var
  low, high, median, middle, ll, hh: PtrInt;
begin
  if n = 0 then
  begin
    result := 0;
    exit;
  end;
  if n = 1 then
  begin
    result := Values[0];
    exit;
  end;
  low := 0;
  high := n - 1;
  median := high shr 1;
  repeat
    if high <= low then
    begin
      // one item left
      result := Values[median];
      exit;
    end;
    if high = low + 1 then
    begin
      // two items -> return the smallest (not average)
      if Values[low] > Values[high] then
        Exchg32(Values[low], Values[high]);
      result := Values[median];
      exit;
    end;
    // find median of low, middle and high items; swap into position low
    middle := (low + high) shr 1;
    if Values[middle] > Values[high] then
      Exchg32(Values[middle], Values[high]);
    if Values[low] > Values[high] then
      Exchg32(Values[low], Values[high]);
    if Values[middle] > Values[low] then
      Exchg32(Values[middle], Values[low]);
    // swap low item (now in position middle) into position (low+1)
    Exchg32(Values[middle], Values[low + 1]);
    // nibble from each end towards middle, swapping items when stuck
    ll := low + 1;
    hh := high;
    repeat
      repeat
        inc(ll);
      until not (Values[low] > Values[ll]);
      repeat
        dec(hh);
      until not (Values[hh] > Values[low]);
      if hh < ll then
        break;
      Exchg32(Values[ll], Values[hh]);
    until false;
    // swap middle item (in position low) back into correct position
    Exchg32(Values[low], Values[hh]);
    // next active partition
    if hh <= median then
      low := ll;
    if hh >= median then
      high := hh - 1;
  until false;
end;
```

You will find something working with any data in [our mormot.core.base.pas unit](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot2/blob/0f62087fd186de032beaae2118a2d2b76c2bad20/src/core/mormot.core.base.pas#L6894).